# How to create loop to correct the gender in datatframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I got new column of 'gender' of df summarized as below after using gender_guesser.detector package. I want change 'mostly_female' to 'female'; and change 'mostly_male"  & 'andy' to 'male'; I wrote codes as below, but generate error. How to fix it? Thanks a lot!
unknown          1125
male              321
female            225
mostly_male        29
mostly_female      26
andy               15

import random
import numpy as np

for index, g in df.iterrows():

```
if g == 'mostly_female':
    df.loc[index, 'gender'] = 'female'

elif g == 'mostly_male':
    df.loc[index, 'gender'] = 'male' 

elif g == 'andy':
    df.loc[index, 'gender'] = 'male'

elif g  == 'unknown':
    df.loc[index, 'gender'] = np.random.choice(['female', 'male'], size=1)

else: 
    print('error')
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

In additional, any suggestion how to revise "unknown" to "male" and " female" according to "first name"?

I really need to change "unknown" to male/female separately, but don't how to handle 1130 observation. So many name here ... 'Cyrenna', 'Dacks', 'Daella', 'Daella', 'Daemon', 'Daeron', 'Daeron', 'Dafyn', 'Dagon', 'Dake', 'Danwell', 'Daughter', 'Delena', 'Dickon', 'Donel', 'Harren', 'Harrold', 'Harwyn', 'Hoarfrost', 'Hoke', 'Hot', 'Hother', 'Humfrey', 'Humfrey', 'Jaremy', 'Jeor', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Donnel', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Jhaqo', 'Jhiqui', 'Aegon', 'Aegon', 'Aerion', 'Aladale', 'Alester', 'Bannen', 'Belandra', 'Belwas', 'Benjen', 'Benjen', 'Beric', 'Black', 'Bore'

Comment: Don’t you want g[“gender”] = ?

Comment: Reading the docs should be your first reflex when using a new library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` method by passing replacement value for every key you need.

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({
      'mostly_female': 'female', 
      'mostly_male': 'male', 
      'andy': 'male',
      'unknown': np.random.choice(['female', 'male'], size=1)
})
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `'unknown'` will get evaluated once so if changing all unknowns to either male/female is what's desired this is fine... If each individual unknown should be changed to male/female separately then you'd need to take a different approach.

Comment: @JonClements You're right, and I think that's what OP wanted.

Comment: I really need to change "unknown" to male/female separately, but don't how to handle 1130 observation. So many name here ... 'Cyrenna', 'Dacks', 'Daella', 'Daella', 'Daemon', 'Daeron', 'Daeron', 'Dafyn', 'Dagon', 'Dake', 'Danwell', 'Daughter', 'Delena', 'Dickon', 'Donel', 'Harren', 'Harrold', 'Harwyn', 'Hoarfrost', 'Hoke', 'Hot', 'Hother', 'Humfrey', 'Humfrey',  'Jaremy', 'Jeor', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Donnel', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Jeyne', 'Jhaqo', 'Jhiqui', 'Aegon',  'Aegon', 'Aerion', 'Aladale', 'Alester', 'Bannen', 'Belandra', 'Belwas', 'Benjen', 'Benjen', 'Beric', 'Black', 'Bore'